# C++ ostream << Operator

Tags: c++, operators

I have a `Class` that deals with Music Albums. The `artists` and `albums` are `strings`. It also has a collection (`vector`) of tracks called `contents`. Each track has a `title` and a `duration`.

This is my `ostream <<`:

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Album& a){
        ostr << "Album: "    << a.getAlbumTitle() << ", ";
        ostr << "Artist: "   << a.getArtistName() << ", ";
        ostr << "Contents: " << a.getContents()   << ". "; //error thrown here
        return ostr;
    }
```

The `<<` next to the `a.getContents()` is underlined and says: `"Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands.`

What am I missing out or doing wrong? Can you not use vectors in this way? or maybe its something I'm missing from my Track class?

Comment: What does `Album::getContents()` return?

Comment: What does `getContents` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Album::getContents()` returns `std::vector<Track>`, you need to provide

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Track& t);
```

and

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::vector<Track>& v);
```

where the latter can use the former. For example:

```
struct Track
{
  int duration;
  std::string title;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Track& t)
{
  return o <<"Track[ " << t.title << ", " << t.duration << "]";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::vector<Track>& v)
{
  for (const auto& t : v) {
    o << t << " ";
  }
  return o;
}
```

There's a C++03 demo [here](http://ideone.com/GFmFCl).

Comment: Ignore my last comment, it was a typo. Unfortunately it says "can not deduce auto type"?

Comment: Change the loop to use either indices or iterators.

Comment: @qwertyRocker it means your compiler probably doesn't support C++11 range based loops. You could try with iterators. See a C++03 version [here](http://ideone.com/GFmFCl).

Answer (score 0):

If `Album::getContents()` is about your vector and you just return the `vector` than `ostream` does not know how to write it, because there is no `'<<' operator`.

Just overload the `'<<' operator` for a `vector` and you are happy.